# Why does clicking the tabs inside a Content Editor Web Part cause my page to refresh?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, html, html-form-web-part

I'm back with more questions. I recently wrote up some HTML (to create a set of three tabs) and put it on the page with the HTML Form Web Part. But now, whenever I click on one of the tabs in order to view the content, the entire page refreshes. How can I stop that from happening?

For reference, here's the code, although I can't see how that could be causing the issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial;}

/* Style the tab */
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.tabcontent {
  animation: fadeEffect 1s; /* Fading effect takes 1 second */
}

/* Gofrom zero to full opacity */
@keyframes fadeEffect {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Further information for Admin Users can be found <a href=" ">here.</a>
```

```
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">New User's 
Guide</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">How To's</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Madrid')">What to Know</button>
```

```
<!--This is New User's Guide-->
<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Links to Training Videos</h3>

  <ol>

  </ol>
  <ul>

  </ul>
</div>


<!-- This is How To's-->
<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">

  <style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>For Cases</h2>
    <ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>For Technical Inventory</h2>
    <ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>For Accountable Inventory</h2>
    <ul>

  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
    <h2>For JI Requirements</h2>
    <ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html> 
</div>


<!-- This is What to Know-->
<div id="Madrid" class="tabcontent">
  <style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>

<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Cases</h2>
   <ul>

</ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Inventory</h2>
     <ul>

     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>JI Requirements</h2>

  </div>
</div>



<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because a `button`'s default behavior is to submit a form, and if you are working in a CEWP on a web part page, that ends up being inside a `form` element on the page, so your button clicks attempt to submit the form, which causes a postback to the server.

You can fix it by adding an attribute `type="button"` to your buttons, i.e.:

```
<button class="tablinks" type="button" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">New User's 
Guide</button>
```

Read more about the possible values for the `type` attribute and what they do [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: And again, you've solved my problem. This is the correct answer.